# Need help with finding length of sides and angles of a triangle in upper half plane model

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry

The given points are $i, 3i, 1 + 2i$

I know that the distance for points on a vertical line can be found by using the formula

$$\ln\left|\frac{y_2}{y_1}\right|$$

So the distance between points $ i$ and $3i$ would be $\ln 3$. How can I get the length between the other sides and the angles of the triangle?

Comment: That's some weird metric. Usually distance between points $z_1$ and $z_2$ is $d = |z_2-z_1| = \sqrt{\left(x_2-x_1\right)^2 + \left(y_2-y_1\right)^2}$, and for the points on vertical line it's $d =|y_2-y_1|$.

Comment: @Kaster - If I'm not wrong, you're describing Euclidean space. I was looking for the length in upper half plane hyperbolic model.

Comment: All the conformal(holomorphic) bijection of upper half plane to itself doesn't change the length,i.e., they're isometry. So you could after an isometry to take the circle passing through i and 1+2i with center at real axis to a vertical line.

Comment: @user74938 Oh, I overlooked that part. I'm indeed not familiar with that concept, but just in case, is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model) what you mean by upper half-plane model?

Comment: @Kaster, that's it. I show how to parametrize the geodesics in my answer.

Comment: @WillJagy I asked because in that wiki-article there's an expression for distance between two points.

Comment: @Kaster, yes, I've never memorized that. On the other hand, I went through the geodesic equations for that metric from start to finish, and I have memorized the unit speed parametrizations. Note that Mobius transformations, real coefficients and positive determinant, are isometries.

Answer (score 2):

The two flavors of unit speed geodesics, in the upper half plane, are the one you know, $$ \alpha(t) = A + i e^t,    $$ for real constant $A$, and
$$ \beta(t) =  A + B \tanh t + i B \operatorname{sech} t  $$ for real constants $A,B$ with $B > 0.$

Since people do not appear to be familiar with the second type, I request that you ask your instructor about it.

My impression from MSE questions from the past week or two is that people are being taught that Möbius transformations (with positive matrix determinant and real entries) give isometries. If you apply the map $-1/z$ to the vertical line, $ \alpha(t) = A + i e^t,    $ you get one example of the second type, which travels along a semicircle with center on the real line. This can be moved about and $B$ changed with additional Möbius transformations.

You should be able to finish from here. You need to find the $A,B$ and two $t$ values along two circular arcs. The difference in $t$ values is the length of that arc in the model.

Or, you can use a Möbius transformation that maps two points to other points with the same real part, in which case you can use your little logarithm. Probably about the same amount of work.